# How to get only the matching elements of an array?

Tags: mongodb

My database content is

```
[
  {
    "_id": "com.aa.bb",
    "rating": [
      {
        "user": "BDB",
        "value": "1"
      },
      {
        "user": "BD",
        "value": "2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to find the records for user 'BD'. When i execute the below query it returns records for users 'BD' and "BDB'. Is it possible to find the exact match ?

Query used - db.coll.find({'_id' : 'com.aa.bb', 'rating.user': 'BD'}

Comment: It is really hard to understand what exactly do you want to achieve.

Comment: please refer the aggregation documentation of mongodb.... http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with [aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/).

First you use the [$unwind operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) to turn the array into a stream of documents.

Then you use [$match](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) to filter those of the user you want.

```
db.coll.aggregate(
    { 
        $match: { 
            "_id": "com.aa.bb"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind:"$rating"
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "rating.user":"BD"
        }
    }
})
```